# ORA-01843: not a valid month: Oracle error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I've written a below oracle query but getting ORA-01843: not a valid month: Oracle error

```
select distinct info1,info2,TIMESTAMP  
from db_1
where info1 = '3.14' 
and TRUNC(TIMESTAMP) = to_date('8/19/2015 5:58:51.420000 AM','mm/dd/yyyy')
```

I need to display only Date in TIMESTAMP column but getting error. Pls help.

Comment: The month symbol is MM: select to_date('8/19/2015','MM/dd/yyyy') from dual

Comment: after making it to MM, I'm getting below error:

ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Comment: Are you sure that's where the error comes from? I get "ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string".

Comment: @AmitBaghel AFAIK format model codes are not case-sensitive.

Comment: @bdn02 - the format elements are case-insensitive, so `mm` is fine (as is `dd` and `yyyy`). The case only matters converting from a date back to a string, and then only for text elements - so `to_char()` treats `mon`, `Mon` and `MON` differently). The original ORA-01843 would come from using `dd/mm/yyyy` instead, perhaps. The code shown can only get ORA-01830. And if the whole format mask was there it would not match the trunc'd timestamp anyway.

Comment: Is this your real code or some test case you composed for the question? It's weird you type a string with milliseconds just to enter a calendar day.

Comment: Yes, the first parameter of "to_date" must have the same format of the second parameter, look my select

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the timestamp part in your where clause and use TRUNC in the SELECT, like this:

```
select distinct info1, info2, trunc(TIMESTAMP) as timestamp 
  from db_1
 where info1 = '3.14' 
   and TRUNC(TIMESTAMP) = to_date('8/19/2015','mm/dd/yyyy');
```

OR do this:

```
select distinct info1, info2, trunc(TIMESTAMP) as timestamp
  from db_1
 where info1 = '3.14' 
   and TIMESTAMP = to_timestamp('8/19/2015 5:58:51.420000 AM','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss.ff AM');
```